# How to use Vim surround to surround paragraph on current beginning and ending lines of the paragraph?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm using tpope's [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).  Example:

Apply `ysip]` to

```
[1 0]
[0 1]
```

will yield

```
[
 [1 0]
 [0 1]
 ]
```

Instead, I'd like to the output to look like

```
[[1 0]
 [0 1]]
```

I have also tried this surround with all the visual mode variants I can think of (i.e. `vip]`, `VjS]`, etc.)

and am still having no luck.  I'm new to text objects and plugin customizing, and just thought I'd ask of any quick solutions before I try editing the surround file.

Edit:  I also found `{jv}k$hS]` was the general solution for what I needed as a remapping!

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, the only way to obtain what you want is to select your text in visual mode (not visual-line or visual-block):

```
v$jS]
```